# スクレイピングでhref属性値の一部の値を取得したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping

**環境**

ruby 2.7.2
rails 6.1
macOS

**前提**

ポートフォリオ作成のため、現在自作アプリを実装しております。
その中で、DBに必要なデータを保存するため、Rubyのnokogiriでスクレイピングを行なっています。

**解決したいこと**

下記のhref属性値から緯度、経度の値を取得したいです（34.907757が緯度で134.859368が経度です）

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://maps.google.com/?q=34.907757,134.859368">GoogleMapsで見る</a>
```

**試したこと**

nokogiriに関する記事を探したのですが、実現させたいことが記述している記事を見つけることができませんでした、、

詳しい方がいましたら是非アドバイスいただけると幸いです。
何卒よろしくお願いします。

**該当するソースコード**

`db/schema.rb`

```
  create_table "spots", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name", null: false
    t.string "time"
    t.string "location"
    t.text "feature"
    t.string "image"
    t.string "url"
    t.float "latitude"
    t.float "longitude"
    t.integer "area_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["area_id"], name: "index_spots_on_area_id"
  end
```

`app/models/scraping.rb`

```
class Scraping < ApplicationRecord
  require 'open-uri'
  require 'nokogiri'

  def self.spot_scrape
    base_url = 'https://loconavi.jp/'
    features_url = 'features/hananomeisho'
    url = "#{base_url}#{features_url}"

    20.times do |i|
      html = URI.open(url).read
      doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(html)

      flower_href = doc.css('.flower')[i]["href"]
      next_url = "#{base_url}#{flower_href}"

      3.times do |i|
        html = URI.open(next_url).read
        doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(html)
        # href属性値の取得(相対URL)。また、_[i]_はtimesメソッドの変数で、繰り返すことに1づつ数値が増えていく
        href = doc.css('.flower-spot')[i]["href"]
        # 相対URLから絶対URLを作成
        link_url = "#{base_url}#{href}"

        html = URI.open(link_url).read
        doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(html)

        doc.css('.main-left-layout').each do | node |
          sleep 1
          # DBに取得したデータを保存
          Spot.create!(
            name: node.at_css('.block').inner_text,
            time: node.css('.spot-info > .t-cell')[1].inner_text,
            location: node.css('.spot-info > .t-row > .t-cell')[1].inner_text,
            feature: node.at_css('.text').inner_text,
            image: node.at_css('img').attribute('src'),
            url: node.at_css('#information p a')["href"],
            latitude: node.at_css('#information p > a')[1]["href"], # コード未完成
            longitude: node.at_css('#information p > a')[1]["href"] # コード未完成
          )
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

正規表現を利用した方法を紹介します。

記述してある `node.at_css('#information p > a')[1]["href"]` ではうまくnodeがとれなかったので範囲内のaタグのリンク先を見て探すようにしました

```rb
base_url = "https://loconavi.jp/"
features_url = "features/hananomeisho"
url = "#{base_url}#{features_url}"
# google mapsの正規表現、緯度経度をキャプチャする
maps_regexp = /\Ahttp:\/\/maps\.google\.com\/\?q=(.+),(.+)\z/

# -- 省略 ---
    doc.css(".main-left-layout").each do |node|
      latitude, longitude = nil, nil
      node.css("a").each do |node|
        # aタグを絞り込み正規表現にマッチするリンクを探す
        result = maps_regexp.match(node[:href])

        # アンマッチの場合はnilなので次の要素へ
        next if result.nil?

        # match:マッチ全体 latitude:緯度 longitude:経度
        match, latitude, longitude = result.to_a
      end
      puts latitude
      puts longitude
      # DBに取得したデータを保存
# -- 省略 ---
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

以下は [String#scan](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/method/String/i/scan.html) を使う方法です。

```rb
doc.css('.main-left-layout').each do |node|
  coord = node.css('a').each {|m|
    coord = m['href'].scan(/http:\/\/maps\.google\.com\/\?q=([\d.]+),([\d.]+)/)
    if coord.any?
      break {:lat => coord[0][0], :lng => coord[0][1]}
    end
  }
  p coord

  # DBに取得したデータを保存
               :
end

## p coord の出力結果
{:lat=>"34.907757", :lng=>"134.859368"}
```

Answer (score 0):

回答いただき、ありがとうございます。
回答をもとにコードを修正した所、緯度、経度の値を取得し、無事DBに保存することができました。

`app/models/scraping.rb`

```
class Scraping < ApplicationRecord
  require 'open-uri'
  require 'nokogiri'

  def self.spot_scrape
    base_url = 'https://loconavi.jp/'
    features_url = 'features/hananomeisho'
    url = "#{base_url}#{features_url}"
    # google mapsの正規表現、緯度経度をキャプチャする
    maps_regexp = /\Ahttp:\/\/maps\.google\.com\/\?q=(.+),(.+)\z/

    20.times do |i|
      html = URI.open(url).read
      doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(html)

      if doc.css('.flower')[i] == nil
        break
      end

      flower_href = doc.css('.flower')[i]["href"]
      next_url = "#{base_url}#{flower_href}"

      3.times do |i|
        html = URI.open(next_url).read
        doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(html)

        # 取得したいスポットがない場合、次のループに移行
        if doc.css('.flower-spot')[i] == nil
          next
        end
        # href属性値の取得(相対URL)。また、_[i]_はtimesメソッドの変数で、繰り返すことに1づつ数値が増えていく
        href = doc.css('.flower-spot')[i]["href"]
        # 相対URLから絶対URLを作成
        link_url = "#{base_url}#{href}"

        html = URI.open(link_url).read
        doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(html)

        doc.css('.main-left-layout').each do | node |
          sleep 0.5

          latitude, longitude = nil, nil
          node.css("a").each do |node|
            # aタグを絞り込み正規表現にマッチするリンクを探す
            result = maps_regexp.match(node[:href])
            # アンマッチの場合はnilなので次の要素へ
            next if result.nil?
            # match:マッチ全体 latitude:緯度 longitude:経度
            match, latitude, longitude = result.to_a
          end

          # データが取得できなかった場合、次のループに移行
          if node.at_css('.block') == nil \
            || node.css('.spot-info > .t-cell')[1] == nil \
            || node.css('.spot-info > .t-row > .t-cell')[1] == nil \
            || node.at_css('.text') == nil \
            || node.at_css('img') == nil \
            || node.at_css('#information p a') == nil
            next
          end

          # DBに取得したデータを保存
          Spot.create!(
            name: node.at_css('.block').inner_text,
            time: node.css('.spot-info > .t-cell')[1].inner_text,
            location: node.css('.spot-info > .t-row > .t-cell')[1].inner_text,
            feature: node.at_css('.text').inner_text,
            image: node.at_css('img').attribute('src'),
            url: node.at_css('#information p a')["href"],
            latitude: latitude,
            longitude: longitude
          )
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```